# using self referencing in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, foreign-keys, self-reference

```
create table EMP(Eid int primary key)

insert into EMP values(11e3)
```

--self referencing

```
alter table EMP 
add constraint fk_EMP_Eid 
foreign key (Eid) references EMP(Eid)
```

--now insert

```
insert into EMP values(12e2)
```

But, this insert should fail, because there is no previous value of `Eid=1200` in the EMP table, so when the foreign key will reference this column , then it would not find the value, hence should fail the insert .

but why does it succeeds?

Comment: WHen you insert the value `12e2` into your `EMP` table (and into its `Eid` column), then that value does exist - so the reference is satisfied...

Comment: It seems very odd that you would be self-referencing on the same column.... that really doesn't make a lot of sense. Typically, what you'd have is `Employee(ID INT, ReportsTo INT)` and that `ReportsTo` column would self-reference `Employee(ID)` so that you could model employee-->boss relationships. But self-referencing on the same column..... what's your scenario, what do you want to do with this???

Comment: @marc_s : no sir. i haven't inserted 1200 beforehand in the table. or you mean to say that the fk constraint after the row is inserted?if yes, then it checks that does 1200 exists, and answer is yes, so it succeeds ,but this would d o a double insert then?

Comment: am just trying to learn about self-referencing , so trying it on a simple example i.e. on a single column table

Comment: @marc_s , sir, is the working of foreign key like this: on passing an insert query, sql first inserts the value, and then the key checks that if this value exists in the parent table, if not, then it rollbacks the insert. is this the working of the fkey?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The column references itself.

So the addition of the row itself guarantees that there is a matching row. This constraint can never fail.

In fact looking at the execution plan SQL Server realises this and doesn't even bother checking it. There is no `assert` operator present.

[image: Plan]

If we create a more typical Employee table there are different plans for the inserts that can violate the constraint as below.

```
create table EMP2(Eid int primary key, boss_id int null);
alter table EMP2 add constraint fk_EMP2_Eid 
 foreign key (boss_id) references EMP2(Eid)

insert into EMP2 values(1,null) /*Can't violate constraint as NULL*/
insert into EMP2 values(2,1)    /*Can violate constraint as NOT NULL*/
```

[image: Plan]

If you try multiple rows a [blocking spool](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/operator-of-the-week---spools,-eager-spool/) is added to the plan so the constraints aren't checked until all rows are inserted.

```
insert into EMP2 values (3,2),(4,3) /*Can violate constraint - multiple rows*/
```

[image: Plan]

And just for completeness as it was raised in the comments, looking at the case when the insert is to a table with a FK referencing a different one...

```
CREATE TABLE EmpSalaryHistory
(
Eid INT NOT NULL REFERENCES EMP(Eid),
EffectiveDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
Salary INT,
PRIMARY KEY (Eid,EffectiveDate)
)

INSERT INTO EmpSalaryHistory
VALUES    (1,GETDATE(),50000),
          (2,GETDATE(),50000)
```

In this instance no spool is added to the plan it can check as it inserts each row rather than all at the end so it can rollback earlier in the event that a row fails (the end result will be the same)

[image: Plan]

Comment: the foreign key says that if a value exists in the parent table, then insert that value in the child table, else not. so here, the parent and child table is EMP. so it checks that does 1200 exist in the parent table, answer is NO, so it should fail the insert. is this the working?

Comment: @sqlchild - It checks the constraints are fulfilled after the rows are inserted.

Comment: ok sir, so in case when parent and child tables are different, example: a parent table has no record, then , on inserting a value in the child table , first it inserts the row in the child table , then it checks in the parent table that if that row exists, and here it did not find it, so it would rollback. am i right sir?

Comment: @sqlchild - Yep, That's correct. In this instance it can check as it inserts rows rather than all at the end so it can rollback earlier in the event that a row fails (the end result will be the same)

Comment: @sqlchild: The fact that the row is actually inserted before the parent is looked up can be easily verified if you have an identity column in the child table. Check the child table's current identity value before inserting (`IDENT_CURRENT('tablename')`), then try to insert a row that violates the foreign key, then check the identity value again. You'll see that it has incremented, which proves that the row was inserted but then the internal transaction was rolled back due to the violation of the foreign key.

Answer (score 0):

Your FK column fk_EMP_Eid probably allows nulls, therefore the relationship isn't required to exist, but if you do try to put a value in that column, then SQL Server will verify that the FK is valid or else it will error.

Answer (score 0):

I created this example for self refernce key for ms sql server

```
CREATE TABLE Category (
   CategoryId int IDENTITY(1,1) not null,
   ParentId int null,
   CONSTRAINT PK_CategoryId PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (CategoryId),
   CONSTRAINT FK_ParentId FOREIGN KEY (ParentId) REFERENCES  Category(CategoryId),
   Title nvarchar(255) NOT NULL
);

insert into category(title)
values
('category1');

insert into category(title,parentid)
values
('category2',1);
```